# Python: can a test file be imported NOT as "module"?

Tags: python, module

So in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases in the section "Command-Line Interface" it is stated "If you want to execute a test file that isn’t importable as a module you should execute the file directly instead.".

My question is: can a test file (or any python file for that matter) be imported not as a module? Until now, I assumed that everytime you import something in python you import it as a module... I mean a module is basically just a python file with statments and definitons right? What qualifies to not being "importable as a module"?

Cheers!

Comment: The short answer is yes & no. Yes if it is in the same directory, no if it is in some other directory. If you wish to run all the python files or test files as a collection of functionalities that interact with each other, then in that case it needs to be a module with a directory containing the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: can a test file (or any python file for that matter) be imported not as a module?

No. "importable as a module" is a single concept, and what you quote is about test files which are *not* that, meaning they are only executable as scripts.

> What qualifies to not being "importable as a module"?

That they won't import, either at all (because they will blow up due to PYTHONPATH divergence), or because they will immediately start running code and will misbehave when imported.

Here the context is of files being run by the unittest test runner, that test runner expects a relatively specific contract (specifically named `TestCase` subclasses, or a `load_tests` function). But there are lots of older test suites in which you'd directly run the files, and trying to run them through the unittest test runner can lead to odd behaviours.